# How to add multiple videos on fotorama gallery in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, fotorama, product-video

I have to add multiple videos for each product on fotorama gallery. I am using this code, and it is working fine for a single video.

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],  function($) {
$(document).on('gallery:loaded', function () {
    var $fotorama = jQuery('div.gallery-placeholder > div.fotorama');
    var fotorama = $fotorama.data('fotorama');
    var video = '<?php echo $video_set[$i]; ?>';
    $fotorama.on('fotorama:load', function fotorama_onLoad(e, fotorama, extra) {
        if (extra.frame.type === 'iframe') {
            extra.frame.$stageFrame.html('<iframe align="middle" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="' + extra.frame.src + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>');
        }
    });
    fotorama.push({ thumb: 'http://127.0.0.1/Magentonew/pub/media/file-MrylO8jADD.png', 'src': video, type: 'iframe',caption: 'SET CAPTION',class: 'prod-video' });
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is only last video is playing when click on thumb image. other videos are showing only its thumb image.
[image]

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. I added videos like this, and it is working fine..

```
fotorama.push({ thumb: 'http://127.0.0.1/Magentonew/pub/media/file-MrylO8jADD11.png', 'src': video1, type: 'iframe',caption: 'SET CAPTION' },{ thumb: 'http://127.0.0.1/Magentonew/pub/media/file-MrylO8jADD11.png', 'src': video2, type: 'iframe',caption: 'SET CAPTION' },{ thumb: 'http://127.0.0.1/Magentonew/pub/media/file-MrylO8jADD11.png', 'src': video3, type: 'iframe',caption: 'SET CAPTION' },{ thumb: 'http://127.0.0.1/Magentonew/pub/media/file-MrylO8jADD11.png', 'src': video4, type: 'iframe',caption: 'SET CAPTION' });
```

Comment: thanks, it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have problem. After video loading 1-2 second, It's stop and show charactor same image . Help me please.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/186583)

Comment: sorry , Now I add new post finish https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330090/magento-2-show-character-after-i-put-custom-video-on-product-page