# Magento 2 - Show character after i put custom video on product page

Tags: magento2.3.2, product-video

I add custom product video in fotorama gallery, but after video pay 2-3 second. It's stop and show character same image . Help me please. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with different videos this looks like the Header for the video is unsupported

Comment: Hello Dava Gordon , Now i create new page for iframe and it's ok, Thank you